# Nginx,Uwsgi and Django App Not Found

Tags: centos, nginx, python, django, uwsgi

I have configured Nginx with uWSGI and Django on CentOS.

Django Directory(contains all my django app): **/home**

Django Project Directory: **/home/hdblog**

**/home/hdapp.py** contains below:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append('/home')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'hdblog.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi

application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

And i'm using below command:

```
/etc/init.d/uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:8889 --master --workers 2 --harakiri 30 --disable-logging --daemonize /tmp/daemonize.log --pidfile /tmp/pidfile.txt --vacuum --gid 500 --uid 500 --pythonpath /home/hdblog --module hdapp
```

Plus,my /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf contains to below line:

```
location / {
         include uwsgi_params;
         uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8889;
    }
```

As you can see everything is ok,but i'm seeing on 80 port

```
uWSGI Error

Python application not found
```

How to solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If the module hdapp map to the file /home/hdapp.py, you have to add /home to the pythonpath